# Prepend items to jQuery Masonry

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

I have been able to append items to jQuery masonry quite happily in order to create an "infinite scroll" affect.

I naively thought similar strategies would work for adding content before the Masonified content.

I setup masonry like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   var $container = $('#pics');
        $container.imagesLoaded( 
        function(){
            $container.masonry({ 
            itemSelector : '.item',
            isFitWidth: true,
            isAnimated: true });
        });
});
```

The original images appear within this loop (using Playframework 1.2.4 with Java)

```
<div id="pics" class="pics">
            #{list items:pics, as:'pic'}
                <div class="item">
                    <a href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/${pic.url}"/>
                    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/${pic.url}" class="pic" style="height:${pic.height}">
                    </a>
                </div>
            #{/list}
</div>
```

And this is where I am adding the new pictures into the Masonified "newpics" div:

```
  $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {

var filename_leaf = milliTime+"-"+file.name;
var filename_stem = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/";
var filename = filename_stem+filename_leaf;

var newpic = "<div class='item'>"+
   "<a href='"+filename+"'>"+
   "<img src='"+filename+"'"+
   " class='pic' style='height:"+file.height+"'>"+
   "</a></div>";

$('#pics').prepend(newpic).masonry('reload');

 });
```

What happens is that the pictures are prepended, however they fall behind the existing pictures.

If there was someway of refreshing/reloading the #pics div without refreshing the whole page that would pretty much solve the problem. I'm going to keep looking, but I suspect that someone else may know a better way.

Comment: The code seems good at first. Are you sure the elements are really prepended and got the correct markup? Do you have any live example? The masonry example is here and the code is basically looking the same: http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/adding-items.html

Comment: Hi Simon, don't have a live example yet. I think the code is correct. But I think prepending might just not be possible, because what happens is you need more space otherwise the items overlap. Do you know of any exampples of prepending that work. I'm going to post a hack that I've come up with (in 10 sec).

Comment: The link I posted in my previous comments links to a working example of prepending elements (from Masonry docs)

Comment: Apologies, I'll take a look at that in more detail.

Comment: I'm going to try replicate his exactly, if not I can probably get this onto heroku in a few min

Comment: Sorry still pushing to heroku atm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem isn't with Masonry. Your bug is that once the new photo is uploaded, the height value is undefined. This means that your picture markup look like this:

```
<img style="height:undefined" class="pic" src="/photo.jpg">
```

This causes problems because until getting the image, most browsers will render the picture as being `height: 0`. And this is what making the `reload` of the masonry mosaic *"buggy"* (it relayout the mosaic considering the first new image as being `0px` in height).

So, you should make sure you got a valid value for the `height` of the image. Or wait until the image is fully loaded to trigger the `reload` method.

Comment: Thanks Simon, I'd looked at that initially, and then totally forgot. Thanks very much for your help :)

Comment: Simon I unaccepted the answer so I can wait a few days and award a bounty. You really helped me out on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Just incase someone finds this. `reload` doesn't work on the current version if you prepend a new element. You have to use `prepended`. Seems like every site references `reload`. Must be for previous versions.

```
msnry.prepended( elements )
// or with jQuery
$container.masonry( 'prepended', elements )
```

http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html